# Redirect upon buton condition clicked

Tags: javascript

I have my home page that I would like to automatically redirect to another page. On the other hand I would like to be able to access it if I click on the button of my menu.

In my header file :

```
   <a class="header__menu-url header__menu-requests" href="/hc/en-us/" id="Home" >
```

In my home page :

```
    <script>
document.getElementById('Home').onclick = handleClick;

function handleClick(e) {
    var sender = (e && e.target) || (window.event && window.event.srcElement);
    if (sender.id != "Home") {
            window.location.href = '/hc/fr-fr/requests'    
  }
}
</script>
<div class="container">
  <div id="main-content">
    <h1 class="page__header pright-lg">
      Toolkits
    </h1>
    <div class="hero-inner">
      <h2 class="visibility-hidden">{{ t 'search' }}</h2>
      <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="12" height="12" focusable="false" viewBox="0 0 12 12"
        class="search-icon" aria-hidden="true">
        <circle cx="4.5" cy="4.5" r="4" fill="none" stroke="currentColor" />
        <path stroke="currentColor" stroke-linecap="round" d="M11 11L7.5 7.5" />
      </svg>
      {{search submit=false instant=settings.instant_search class='search search-full'}}
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Thanks

Comment: Are you working with a framework/library?

Comment: it'is zendesk theme , so may be just javascript

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there's enough information here to give you a really great answer, but here's some code I just wrote that does what you want based on your initial question. This will redirect the user the first time they visit the page, but then not again until they close and reopen the browser, allowing them to go back to the first page. It uses vanilla JavaScript and exceptionally basic HTML; it's also assuming that all files are on the same level in the structure. I used setTimeout just to give you time to see the transition, but it could be immediate if you didn't use it.

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
        <title>Document</title>
    </head>
    <body>
      <a id="header" href="header.html">GO TO HEADER</a>
      <script src="index.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

header.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
        <title>Document</title>
    </head>
    <body>
      <a id="index" href="index.html">GO TO INDEX</a>
    </body>
</html>
```

index.js

```
if (!sessionStorage.getItem('visited')) {
    setTimeout(() => {
        window.location.replace('/header.html');
    }, 1000);
    sessionStorage.setItem('visited', 'true');
}
```